# looping values for horizontal lines

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib, plot, mplfinance

I have a for loop that's taking values from functions and appending a list with those values.

```
levels = []
for i in range(2, df.shape[0] - 2):  
    if is_support(df, i):    
        low = df['Low'][i]    
        if is_far_from_level(low, levels, df):      
            levels.append((i, low))  
    elif is_resistance(df, i):    
        high = df['High'][i]    
        if is_far_from_level(high, levels, df):      
            levels.append((i, high))
```

The list is 2D and I only want the second value in each row, so I'm manipulating as:

```
length = len(levels)
test = np.array(levels)
test = test[0:length,1]
test = list(test)
test.sort()
```

Now I want to plot the stock, so

```
fig, axlist = mpf.plot(df,type='candle',style='yahoo',volume=True, 
                     returnfig=True, figsize=(33,12), ylabel="Closing price", hlines=dict(hlines = test,colors=("black"), linewidths=0.5), title=symbol)
```

Now I would like to label the lines with the values from the list, so I'm using

```
axlist[0].annotate(test[0],xy=(len(df)+1,test[0]))
```

But lets say that

```
length = 4
```

and test is

```
[145.45, 184.15, 258.4, 338.9]
```

What I would like to do is instead of doing

```
axlist[0].annotate(test[0],xy=(len(df)+1,test[0]))
axlist[0].annotate(test[1],xy=(len(df)+1,test[1]))
axlist[0].annotate(test[2],xy=(len(df)+1,test[2]))
axlist[0].annotate(test[3],xy=(len(df)+1,test[3]))
```

I'd would like to create a for loop (or something) that appends or expands the axlist with all of the values in test, no matter how many values there are (as known from the variable "length").
I know that I can use

```
for i in test:
    print(i)
```

to see all of the values, and I'm guessing that I can use similar syntax to append the axline code line - but I don't know exactly.

Thanks a lot in advance.

********************* EDIT ******************************

When I'm running my code now, I get this plot:
[image]

along with the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\Andreas\Aktieanalys\fractal charts.py", line 61, in <module>
axlist[0].annotate(test[6],xy=(len(df)+1,test[6]))

IndexError: list index out of range
```

and I assume that the error arises due to the fact that there are no more values in the "levels" list. But set aside the error, this is how I want the annotation for each line.

I tried to do it as suggested, like this:

```
annotations = []     # initialize empty annotation information.
for item in levels:  # main loop

    # work related to plotting level
    text = str(test)                              # set annotation text
    x,y  = (len(df)+1,test[0]) # point to annotate

   # store each annotation as a tuple of "text" and "x,y",
   # where x,y is itself a tuple too:
    annotations.append((text,(x,y) ))
                  # any other work for the main loop
                  
fig, axlist = mpf.plot(df,type='candle',style='yahoo',volume=True, 
                    returnfig=True, figsize=(15,10),         ylabel="Closing price",
      hlines=dict(hlines = test,colors=("black"), linewidths=0.5), title=symbol, 
      )
                  
ax = axlist[0]

for an in annotations:
    ax.annotate(an[0],an[1])
```

Which gives me this plot, where all the values are on the first line.
[image]

I want one values for each line (of course corresponding the right values to the right lines), and I'm thinking that it should be some kind of for-loop, which creates some output that should be something like:

```
axlist[0].annotate(test[n],xy=(len(df)+1,test[n]))    
axlist[0].annotate(test[n+1],xy=(len(df)+1,test[n+1]))
axlist[0].annotate(test[n+2],xy=(len(df)+1,test[n+2]))
axlist[0].annotate(test[n+3],xy=(len(df)+1,test[n+3]))
```

until it reaches the last value in the list levels, so basically

```
len(levels)
```

I hope this makes my question more clear, otherwise let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this is really just a matter of algorithm.  I do something similar to this in one of my plots where I want to annotate every signal.

The simplest thing to do (I have found) is to save the annotation information as you are going through the main loop, and then loop through the annotation information after the plot while calling `Axes.annotate()`.  Something like this (pseudocode) :

```py
annotations = []     # initialize empty annotation information.
for item in levels:  # main loop

   ... # work related to plotting level
   text = str(level)                              # set annotation text
   x,y  = calculate_xy_where_we_want_annotation() # point to annotate

   # store each annotation as a tuple of "text" and "x,y",
   # where x,y is itself a tuple too:
   annotations.append( (text, (x,y)) )
   ... # any other work for the main loop
```

... then later, plot and annotate:

```py
   fig, axlist = mpf.plot(df,...)
   ax = axlist[0]

   for an in annotations:
       ax.annotate(an[0],an[1])
```

---

...

---

If you want to get fancy, you can also set the position of the text relative to the point being annotated:

```py
   for an in annotations:
       x,y = an[1]            # location of point to annotate (need for next line)
       text_xy = (x-1,0.96*y) # text itself slightly below and off to the side)
       ax.annotate(an[0],an[1],xytext=text_xy)
```

and/or set the annotation arrow properties:

```py
   for an in annotations:
       x,y = an[1]            # location of point to annotate (need for next line)
       text_xy = (x-1,0.96*y) # text itself slightly below and off to the side)
       ax.annotate(an[0],an[1],xytext=text_xy,arrowprops=dict(
                   facecolor='r',headwidth=5,width=2,shrink=0.1,alpha=0.75))
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback Daniel. I'm not quite sure if either I did not understand your reply fully or if my question was unclear. I've edited it, please take a look if you can. Basically I want one value for each line, and a for-loop to go through each value in the list "levels" for annotating the lines.  @Daniel